# How to close the application

Tags: android-ndk

I have seven activities in my application. I have exit button in my first activity. When I am first click on the Exit button then it runs ok...... but when i am on second,third......activities and comes direct to the first activity then the Exit Button took me in the previous activity.....

```
    Button Exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
    Exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
            System.exit(1);

        }

    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is designed in a way that it is not necessary to shut down applications. If you want user to get to home-screen you can just create an intent to show home-screen. Something like this: `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);`. No need for `System.exit(1)`.

Comment: i have the option to move the home screen.........But I want to quit the application ?

Comment: If you really want to stop the process for some reason you should check killProcess:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess(int) .

'android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());'